# Get multiple instances of an object registered via Autofac module registration

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, ioc-container

I have a use case where I need to get two copies of objects registered from Autofac module and pass them to register different types.

In the below code sample,

1. I want to pass an object of DataProtectionService with config `dbConfig` to register `MyDbRepo`.
2. Similarly, I want to pass an object of DataProtectionService with config `cacheConfig` to register `MyCacheRepo`.

But, I am not sure how should I do that? Am I missing something really basic here?

I don't have an option to remove this `DataProtectionServiceModule`. Is there a way to achieve what I am expecting?

```cs
public class DataProtectionServiceModule : Module
{
    private readonly string config;

    public DataProtectionServiceModule(string config)
    {
        this.config = config;
    }

    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Register<Token>(compContext =>
        { // a complex logic here
        }).OnRelease(instance => instance.Dispose());

        builder.Register(c =>
        {
            // a logic to generate an object of IDataProtectionService
            // this logic involves the use of config field of this class.
        }).As<IDataProtectionService>();
    }
}

public class MyDbRepo : IMyDbRepo
{
    IDataProtectionService dataProtectionService;
    public MyDbRepo(IDataProtectionService dataProtectionService)
    {
        this.dataProtectionService = dataProtectionService;
    }
}

public class MyCacheRepo : IMyCacheRepo
{
    IDataProtectionService dataProtectionService;
    public MyCacheRepo(IDataProtectionService dataProtectionService)
    {
        this.dataProtectionService = dataProtectionService;
    }
}

// Program.cs of my backend micro service
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterModule(new DataProtectionServiceModule("dbConfig"));
builder.RegisterModule(new DataProtectionServiceModule("cacheConfig")); // I have figured, this is wrong.
builder.RegisterType<MyDbRepo>().As<IMyDbRepo>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<MyCacheRepo>().As<IMyCacheRepo>().SingleInstance();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Keyed Services](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html). And then in your registration add a specific `Resolve`.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");


        // Program.cs of my backend micro service
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterModule(new DataProtectionServiceModule("dbConfig", DeviceState.Db));
        builder.RegisterModule(new DataProtectionServiceModule("cacheConfig", DeviceState.Cache)); // I have figured, this is wrong.
        builder.RegisterType<MyDbRepo>().WithParameter(
            new ResolvedParameter(
                (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(IDataProtectionService),
                (pi, ctx) => ctx.ResolveKeyed<IDataProtectionService>(DeviceState.Db)
            )
        ).As<IMyDbRepo>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<MyCacheRepo>().WithParameter(
            new ResolvedParameter(
                (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(IDataProtectionService),
                (pi, ctx) => ctx.ResolveKeyed<IDataProtectionService>(DeviceState.Cache)
            )
        ).As<IMyCacheRepo>().SingleInstance();

        var container = builder.Build();

        var cache = container.Resolve<IMyCacheRepo>();
        var db = container.Resolve<IMyDbRepo>();

    }
}

public enum DeviceState { Cache, Db }


public class DataProtectionServiceModule : Module
{
    private readonly string config;
    private readonly DeviceState _state;

    public DataProtectionServiceModule(string config, DeviceState state)
    {
        this.config = config;
        _state = state;
    }

    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Register<Token>(compContext =>
        { // a complex logic here
        }).OnRelease(instance => instance.Dispose());

        builder.Register(c =>
        {
            // a logic to generate an object of IDataProtectionService
            // this logic involves the use of config field of this class.
            return new DataProtectionService(config);
        }).Keyed<IDataProtectionService>(_state);
    }
}

public class DataProtectionService : IDataProtectionService
{
    public string Config { get; }

    public DataProtectionService(string config)
    {
        Config = config;
    }
}


public class MyDbRepo : IMyDbRepo
{
    IDataProtectionService dataProtectionService;
    public MyDbRepo(IDataProtectionService dataProtectionService)
    {
        this.dataProtectionService = dataProtectionService;
    }
}

public interface IDataProtectionService
{
}

public interface IMyDbRepo
{
}

public class MyCacheRepo : IMyCacheRepo
{
    IDataProtectionService dataProtectionService;
    public MyCacheRepo(IDataProtectionService dataProtectionService)
    {
        this.dataProtectionService = dataProtectionService;
    }
}

public interface IMyCacheRepo
{
}
```

Alternatively you can use [Named Services](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html#named-services) and the config-name `dbConfig` and `cacheConfig`. This way you do not need to change the constructor of `DataProtectionServiceModule`.

```
    builder.RegisterType<MyDbRepo>().WithParameter(
        new ResolvedParameter(
            (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(IDataProtectionService),
            (pi, ctx) => ctx.ResolveNamed<IDataProtectionService>("dbConfig")
        )
    ).As<IMyDbRepo>().SingleInstance();
    builder.RegisterType<MyCacheRepo>().WithParameter(
        new ResolvedParameter(
            (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(IDataProtectionService),
            (pi, ctx) => ctx.ResolveNamed<IDataProtectionService>("cacheConfig")
```

And your module:

```
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        //builder.Register<Token>(compContext =>
        //{ // a complex logic here
        //}).OnRelease(instance => instance.Dispose());

        builder.Register(c =>
        {
            // a logic to generate an object of IDataProtectionService
            // this logic involves the use of config field of this class.
            return new DataProtectionService(config);
        }).Named<IDataProtectionService>(config);
    }
```

Comment: Will it also work in case I am injecting dependency of IDataProtectionService inside the builder via serviceCollection like this:
```cs
builder.Register(c =>
{
    ServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
    serviceCollection
        .AddDataProtection()  // provided by asp.net

    ServiceProvider serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
    var dataProtectionProvider = serviceProvider.GetDataProtectionProvider();
    return dataProtectionProvider;
}).Named<IDataProtectionService>(this.config);
```

Comment: sorry for the unindented code above. Don't see any immediate way to insert code in comment with proper indentations.

Comment: So, you want to use the `Microsoft.DI` to resolve your instance, and then register *that* instance with Autofac? I don't see why that shouldn't work, as long as the instance is provided to Autofac.